# Radio button on change call a java script function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet from my app where I've created a radio button to change the status of the post.

The following method of getting the function executed gives the message.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: publish is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange

```js
    function publish() {
        let publish = $(this).data('publish');      
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {        
        $.ajax({
            
            type: "POST",
            url: '/manage/post/publish/' + publish,
            data: {
                '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'id': publish,
                "_method": 'PUT'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                Toast.fire({
                    type: data.type,
                    title: data.message
                });
            }
        });

        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
            
            type: "POST",
            url: '/manage/post/unpublish/' + publish,
            data: {
                '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'id': publish,
                "_method": 'PUT'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                Toast.fire({
                    type: data.type,
                    title: data.message
                });
            }
        });
        }
    };
```

```html
@foreach($collection as $item)
<div class="form-group mt-2 mb-2">
  <span class="switch switch-sm">
   <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="status" data-publish="{{$item->id}}" {{$item->status ? 'checked' : ''}}  onchange="publish()">
   <label for="status" class="mb-0">Publish</label>
  </span>
</div>
@endforeach
```

With jquery method:

```js
$("#status").click(function () {
..............
});
```

The it works only on first iteration of the loop. As the `ID` is also being iterated with the loop. The `jQuery` catches the first id.

How can I make this workout ?

Comment: Why not use the `value` attribute instead of `data-publish`?

Comment: ID's are unique. There can only be one of each ID on the page. You could make them dynamic by adding `id="status-{{$item->id}}"` to the `id` and `for` attributes.

Comment: And how do I capture the dynamic ID with jquery ?

Comment: You don't have to. Use the class instead. `$('.status')` will select all your input elements.